# top cpu output interpretation

Tags: top

can anyone explain me please why top is showing me that 53% of the CPU time is consumed by processes in the user mode, when all processes are at almost 0% ???

[image]

Comment: is your top output sorted by CPU usage, or another field... ?

Comment: top -n 1 -b > top-output.txt,     if I'm not mistaken, it should be sorted automatically from the highest to the lowest